# Magic in C recursion? who can explain?

Tags: c, recursion

Can somebody explain to me how this recursion works?
I'm getting stuck on how the result is 20 when the recursion leaves only on if `a == b` and it's `a = 6` and `b = 6`

```
int main() 
{
    printf("%d \n",mistero(2, 6));
    return 0;
}

mistero( a, b)
{
    if( a == b ){
        return a;
    }
    return a + mistero(a+1, b);
}
```

Comment: What's the part you are stuck on? What **do** you already understand about the working of this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your function definition has to be before your main, so that at compile time it is known in the main function otherwise you have to use a function prototype!

Also you forgot to define the return type and the types of the arguments. So your code should looks like this to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mistero(int a, int b) {
//^         ^^^----^^^ variable type
//| Here return type

    if( a == b ) {
        return a;
    }

    return a + mistero(a+1, b);
}

int main() {

    printf("%d \n",mistero(2, 6));

    return 0;
}
```

Or with a function prototype:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mistero(int a,int b);

int main() {

    printf("%d \n",mistero(2, 6));

    return 0;
}


int mistero(int a,int b) {

    if( a == b ){
        return a;
    }

    return a + mistero(a+1, b);
}
```

And this should show how it works:

```
return 2 + mistero(2 + 1, b);
return 2 + 3 + mistero(3 + 1, b);
return 2 + 3 + 4 + mistero(4 + 1, b);
return 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + mistero(5 + 1, b);
return 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6;
                         = 20
```

Answer (score 7):

```
mistero(2, 6) =
2 + mistero(3, 6) =
2 + 3 + mistero(4, 6) =
2 + 3 + 4 + mistero(5, 6) =
2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + mistero(6, 6) =
2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6
                  = 20
```

Answer (score 4):

Recursion works as below:

```
2 + mistero(3,6);

2 + 3 + mistero(4,6)

2 + 3 + 4 + mistero(5,6)

2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + mistero(6,6)

2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6  = 20
```

Answer (score 3):

Just execute the code step by step and replace the function call by the return value.

When the function is first called :

```
return 2 + mistero(3,6);
```

`mistero(3,6)` returns `3 + mistero(4,6)`

so the return statement eventually continues to get added till `a==b`

```
return 2+3+4+5+6
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the confusing aspect to this is the apparent lack of some sort of loop statement. I.e `for` or `do while` statement. 
Think of it this way at the very end of the program.

`return A + MISTERO(A+1, B) /* IS THE LOOP STATEMENT */`

It causes the program to call the function `MISTERO (A , B)` from within the function `MISTERO (A, B)`. So as long as this occurs you get a round about way of a loop. Until the loop is satisfied in the statement test `if(A == B)`. Then the loop is escaped be a simple `return A`. 
Thanks enjoy programming!!!

Comment: If you had a higher rep, I'd suggest that this was more of a comment than an answer. But, as it is, I guess we should let it pass.